# OpenSSL CA Certificate generation failing without error message

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, x509

I want to create a CA Certificate out of a CSR. The process is failing with no error message though, so I don't know where to find a solution.

```
[user@computer myca]$ openssl ca -config openssl.cnf -out user1cert.pem -in user1req.pem
Using configuration from openssl.cnf
[user@computer myca]$
```

My config file looks like this:

```
[ca]
default_ca = CA_default

[CA_default]
dir = . # where everything is kept
new_certs_dir = $dir # default place for new certs
serial = $dir/serial # the current serial number
database = $dir/index # database index file
certificate = $dir/cacert.pem # The CA certificate
private_key = $dir/caprivkey.pem # The private key
RANDFILE = $dir/.rand # private random number file
default_days = 730 # how long to certify for
default_md = sha256 # which message digest to use
policy = policy_any # which policy is used

[policy_any]
countryName = supplied # country name is mandatory
stateOrProvinceName = optional # state is optional
organizationName = optional # organization name is optional
organizationalUnitName = optional # unit name is optional
commonName = optional # user name is mandatory
emailAddress = optional # email address is optional
```

The files that are referenced in the config file (`cacert.pem`, `caprivkey.pem`, `index` and `serial`) all exist the in the current directory. And if I change the name of any of them, I get an error saying the file doesn't exist, so I know error messages are displaying. I also get an error when trying to use a wrong private key, which I did just to test getting an error message.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "I also get an error" - What error?  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your device serial has not already been signed and present in index.txt and index.txt.old
Also check the index.txt.attr and .old also.

Then retry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).