# adding certificate to apache 2.4

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, ssl, openssl

i have 2 servers , both of them are CentOS , one of them acts as CA server (using openssl) and the other one acts as Webserver (using apache 2.4) . i want to setup https for my test website so i did the following steps :

1) in webserver i created a keypair :
[keypair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcabC.png)

2) created a csr request in webserver : 
[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4iod.png)

3) then i copied that to my CA server and created a certifcate file :

[crt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOOG6.png)

4) then i copied back the certificate file into my webserver :
[keyFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v88qs.png)

as you can see i copied both key file and certificate file to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ and /etc/pki/tls/private

5) i created a virtualhost in httpd.conf (which works just fine) and ssl.conf :
[ssl.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiWoS.png)

6) now when i try to restart the httpd service i get the following error : 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPccN.png)

as you can see it says the SSLCertificateFile does not exist or is empty , while it is there and is not empty.

i would be appreciated if you help me solve this issue .

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'd get more response if you pasted the text of your commands and their outputs directly into the question (formatted correctly, of course) instead of as links to images.  It would also help search engines find the question and answer for others who ask similar questions in the future.

Comment: i googled the issue first , but i didn't find any useful answers .

Comment: I'm sure you did, but you've pasted links.  Look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1395921/openssl-ca-certificate-generation-failing-without-error-message) and notice how the OP has pasted the commands as text and formatted those as code (with the `{}` button).

Comment: i see i wanted to change the question format , but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Click the 'edit' link at the bottom of the question. Or, click [here](https://superuser.com/posts/1449553/edit).

Answer (score 0):

`apachectl configtest` usually checking on the syntax in your configuration file. May not reveal naming error or file permission issue.

Try checking these:

1. Copy the link (with certificate name) in the error message and do a `ls -l /etc/pki/xxx`. this is to make sure the syntax in your config file is correct.
2. Check the certificate whether it's corrupted. Example as below:

To verify certificate

> openssl x509 -in /etc/pki/xxx.crt -text -noout

To verify private key

> openssl rsa -in /etc/pki/xxx.key -check

Comment: thank you for your reply : 
i double checked both SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile paths and they were correct .
i also verified certificate and private key as you asked , and both of them seem to have correct syntax and ...

Comment: can you try changing the cert file permission to `600`?

Comment: i changed it , but the error still exist : 
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/pki/tls/certs/mysite.com.crt' does not exist or is empty

Comment: does the folder has permission of `755`?

Comment: the /etc/pki/tls/certs has 755 permission and mysite.com.crt has 600 permission

Comment: Tested at my local machine (ubuntu 16.04, Apache 2.4) and able to run it. I would suggest to regenerate the certificates.

Comment: thank you  . i try using ubuntu this time .